# jQuery to get the values of td inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table id="GridView1">
 <tr>
    <th>KeyWord</th>
    <th>Identifiers</th>
    <th>Values</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <select >
           <option selected="selected" value="Action A">Action A</option>
           <option  value="Action b">Action b</option>
           <option value="Action C">Action C</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <textarea >adsasd</textarea>
    </td>
        <td>
        <textarea >dsad</textarea>
    </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <select >
           <option value="Action A">Action A</option>
           <option selected="selected" value="Action b">Action b</option>
           <option value="Action C">Action C</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <textarea >asdasd</textarea>
    </td>
        <td>
        <textarea >sdsad</textarea>
    </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

This is the js.

```
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
xml = xml + '<Root>';
i=0;
$("#GridView1 tr").each(function () {

 $(this).find('td').each (function() {
    alert($(this).find('select').val())

  alert($(this).find('textarea').val())


});

});

xml = xml + '</Root>'
alert(xml)
```

I am getting all the values inside the td but also getting undefined. Any idea why ?

Comment: Your fiddle is different than code you posted

Comment: why you want dropdown and texarea values like this ? cant you use id or by name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get undefined because it tries to display the select value AND the textarea value for EACH td.

To show only the existing values, just check if the element exists within the td:

```
if($(this).find('textarea').length > 0) {
  alert($(this).find('textarea').val());
}
```

Comment: how to make it show the value only if there is a select or textarea and not otherwise

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/N6TdM/150/)

```
$("table").find("td").each(function(){
alert($(this).html());


})
```

Comment: wow I answered your question and you changed the whole question . why did you put a wrong jsfiddle demo  than ???

Answer (score 0):

Find all `select` and `textarea` in `tr` instead of `td` like following.

```
$("#GridView1 tr").find('select, textarea').each(function () {
    alert(this.value);
});
```